# How can I Deserialize this json? It is giving all null value with following codes

Tags: c#, json

```
{
"Global Quote": {
    "01. symbol": "MSFT",
    "02. latest trading day": "2018-11-19",
    "03. previous close": "108.2900"}
}
```

This is the code I m using:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var objText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    //This line is not working.
    Stock stock = (Stock)js.Deserialize(objText, typeof(Stock));
    return Ok(stock);
}
```

The stock is model as shown below:

```
public class Stock
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public string latesttradingday { get; set; }
    public string previousclose { get; set; } 
}
```

All I m getting is Null in all field of Stock. What I m missing here? I m new to JSON.

Comment: The json has field `01. symbol`. That can not be converted to property `symbol` of class.

Comment: This is funky json

Comment: So there is not any solution for this?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya is there any way to get value 108.2900 only from above data? 
That would work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `JsonProperty`

```
public class GlobalQuote
{
   [JsonProperty("Global Quote")]
   public Stock Stock { get; set; } 
}
public class Stock
{
   [JsonProperty("01. symbol")]
   public string symbol { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("02. latest trading day")]
   public string latesttradingday { get; set; }
   [JsonProperty("03. previous close")]
   public string previousclose { get; set; } 
}
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   string test = @"{
             ""Global Quote"": {
             ""01. symbol"": ""MSFT"",
             ""02. latest trading day"": ""2018-11-19"",
             ""03. previous close"": ""108.2900""}
         }";

   var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GlobalQuote>(test);

}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/88O1ks)

---

**Additional Resources**

[JsonProperty Class](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm)

> Maps a JSON property to a .NET member or constructor parameter.

Comment: Good solution for indeed a funky Json, normally it is for mapping the names using `JsonProperty`, but here we can't even form a class from default Json, +1